# Run a script which down scale the instance during autoscaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I want to run a script when the instances got terminated during autoscaling. basically, I want to do this for two reason.
1. Remove from the monitoring (Third party tool via API)
2. Delete the record set.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use an Autoscaling Lifecycle Hook. Check out the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/introducing-lifecycle-hooks.html).